# Retrieving # contributors on a Wikipedia page using MediaWiki API, "without retrieving the names and other information"

Tags: web-scraping, mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, pywikibot

I am using MediaWiki API, trying to retrieve the number of known and anonymous contributors all together on a Wikipedia page, but the only property that I found is "contributors", which returns all the data about the contributors, so it is really slow.

I wanted to know if there is any efficient way both for me and Wikipedia to retrieve the numbers without retrieving the names and other data, or we should just add this problem to:
https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17993

One more question: Do you think it can be faster if I use Wikipedia database dump instead?

Answer (score 0):

By appending `?action=info` to any mediawiki URL you get an overview of information about the page, including the number of contributors and it is quite fast. However, you need to parse the page yourself then.